# How to capture Hibernate DB connection error exception?

Tags: java, hibernate, exception

I am using Hibernate 3 in my development and WAS Liberty Profile as my local development server. I am trying to create an exception handling when DB server was down. To do this, I am trying simulate the environment by connecting to a fake IP address in `hibernate.cfg.xml` for this testing.

I have the following JAVA code but the exception wasn't catch in the exception code when DB connection wasn't ready. The console output shows the connection could not be obtain as warning. May I know how could I capture my scenario in exception code instead of showing it as a warning?

**JAVA code**

```
   public class HibernateUtil { 
     static {
       try {
         log.info("HibernateUtil.static - Begin");

         if (cacheFactory.get("Factory") == null) {
           sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
           cacheFactory.put("Factory", sessionFactory);
         } else {
           sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) cacheFactory.get("Factory");
         }

         log.info("HibernateUtil.static - end");

       } catch (HibernateException ex) {
         throw new RuntimeException("[Exception] : " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
       }
     }

     ...
     ...
   }
```

**Console output**

```
INFO  2012-09-20 15:24:16,314 [HibernateUtil.java:37] - HibernateUtil.static - Begin

[WARNING ] recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
[WARNING ] Property [hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer] has been renamed to [hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer]; update your properties appropriately
[WARNING ] recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
[WARNING ] Property [hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer] has been renamed to [hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer]; update your properties appropriately
[WARNING ] Could not obtain connection to query metadata

INFO  2012-09-20 15:24:24,001 [HibernateUtil.java:46] - HibernateUtil.static - end
```

**Hibernate configuration**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:db2://192.168.1.6:51201/MYDB</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">myuser</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">MyPassword</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">100</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode">auto</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer">true</property>

    ...

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: `@Santosh` Hibernate configuration has been added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need is `test-on-connection-acquire`

Seems you are using the default Hibernate connection pool. Unfortunately, hibernate connection pool does not support his property and they recommend third party connection pool libraries like C3P0.

The [official documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-hibernatejdbc) of Hibernate discourages using their default connection.

> Hibernate's own connection pooling algorithm is, however, quite
>   rudimentary. It is intended to help you get started and is not
>   intended for use in a production system, or even for performance
>   testing. You should use a third party pool for best performance and
>   stability.

[Here is how](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-configure-the-c3p0-connection-pool-in-hibernate/)  you can configure C3P0 with hibernate. [Here are relevant properties](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#configuring_connection_testing) of C3P0 for testing connections.

Answer (score 0):

What class is generating the warning? My guess would be that you are not catching an Exception because it isn't being thrown. If that is the case, perhaps you could to test if the connection was made in your code and throw the Exception yourself.

Comment: Sorry for my bad. That class is HibernateUtil actaully. I have updated my JAVA code. I have already trace every single statement in debug mode on the code but it just execute perfectly.